# MongoDB Java - Create a new ObjectId for each element of an existing array

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an existing collection, containing several documents.

```json
[{
    "_id": "...1",
    "prop1": "...",
    "prop2": "...",
    "someArray": [
        {
            "value": "sub element 1.1"
        },
        {
            "value": "sub element 1.2"
        },
        {
            "value": "sub element 1.3"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "_id": "...2",
    "prop1": "...",
    "prop2": "...",
    "someArray": [
        {
            "value": "sub element 2.1"
        },
        {
            "value": "sub element 2.2"
        }
    ]
}, // many others here...
]
```

For each root document, I would like to add an `_id` property of type `ObjectId` on each sub-element of `someArray`. So, after I run my command, the content of the collection is the following:

```json
[{
    "_id": "...1",
    "prop1": "...",
    "prop2": "...",
    "someArray": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("..."),
            "value": "sub element 1.1"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("..."),
            "value": "sub element 1.2"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("..."),
            "value": "sub element 1.3"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "_id": "...2",
    "prop1": "...",
    "prop2": "...",
    "someArray": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("..."),
            "value": "sub element 2.1"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("..."),
            "value": "sub element 2.2"
        }
    ]
}, // ...
]
```

Each `ObjectId` being, of course, unique.

The closer I got was with this:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').updateMany({}, { "$set" : { "someArray.$[]._id" : ObjectId() } });
```

But every sub-element of the entire collection ends up with the same ObjectId value...

Ideally, I need to get this working using Java driver for MongoDB. The closest version I got is this (which presents the exact same problem: all the ObjectId created have the same value).

```java
database
    .getCollection("myCollection")
    .updateMany(
        Filters.ne("someArray", Collections.emptyList()), // do not update empty arrays
        new Document("$set", new Document("someArray.$[el]._id", "ObjectId()")), // set the new ObjectId...
        new UpdateOptions().arrayFilters(
            Arrays.asList(Filters.exists("el._id", false)) // ... only when the _id property doesn't already exist
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I managed to write in the end:

```java
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("myCollection");
collection
    .find(Filters.ne("someArray", Collections.emptyList()), MyItem.class)
    .forEach(item -> {
        item.getSomeArray().forEach(element -> {
            if( element.getId() == null ){
                collection.updateOne(
                    Filters.and(
                        Filters.eq("_id", item.getId()),
                        Filters.eq("someArray.value", element.getValue())
                    ),
                    Updates.set("someArray.$._id", new ObjectId())
                );
            }
        });
    });
```

The `value` property of sub-elements had to be unique (and luckily it was). And I had to perform separate `updateOne` operations in order to obtain a different `ObjectId` for each element.

Answer (score 1):

With MongoDB v4.4+, you can use `$function` to use javascript to assign the _id in the array.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "someArray": {
        $function: {
          body: function(arr) {
                  return arr.map(function(elem) {
                           elem['_id'] = new ObjectId(); 
                           return elem;
                         })
                },
          args: [
            "$someArray"
          ],
          lang: "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JUzQ667kx-U) for your reference. (It's slightly different from the code above as playground requires the js code to be in double quote)

---

For older version of MongoDB, you will need to use javascript to loop the documents and update them one by one.

```js
db.getCollection("...").find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.someArray = doc.someArray.map(function(elem) {
    elem['_id'] = new ObjectId(); 
    return elem;
  })
  db.getCollection("...").save(doc);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but `db.version()` returns `3.6.21` :/

Comment: @Eria updated the answer to include the older way of updating documents in MongoDB. Please have a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: I can't use this as-is in Java. The Javascript part does not compile. I will try to find a way to adapt it.

Comment: @Eria you dont need to use this in java. You just need to open a mongo shell and execute the script. Check out [Mongo shell](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/mongo/). It should come natively with your MongoDB.

Comment: Ultimately, I have to put this in a mongock change log, integrated in our app source code. So, yes, I need to translate this in Java ^^'

Comment: @Eria For this new context, I suggest you set the `_id` field in some ORM models to correctly populate the array.